# How to send Kinect skeleton data through Unity networks (multiplayer)

Tags: c#, kinect, unityscript, unity-game-engine

I have a multiplayer game in which two people on different computers have a Kinect v2 in Unity. Therefore, I am using C# to program a host to client network. The main problem I have so far is that I don't know how to submit Kinect skeleton data through the network (trying to pass it through OnSerializeNetworkView() ) in order to sync the skeleton animation simultaneously through the network.

Any suggestions on how to synchronize Kinect movement through a network in Unity?